# error when pulling a docker container using singularity in nextflow

Tags: docker, singularity-container, nextflow

I am making a very short workflow in which I use a tool for my analysis called salmon.
In the `hpc` that I am working in, I cannot install this tool so I decided to pull the container from `biocontainers`.
In the hoc we do not have `docker` installed (I also do not have permission to do so) but we have `singularity` instead.
So I have to pull docker container (`from: quay.io/biocontainers/salmon:1.2.1--hf69c8f4_0)` using singularity.
The workflow management system that I am working with is `nextflow`.
This is the short workflow I made (`index.nf`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env nextflow
nextflow.preview.dsl=2

container = 'quay.io/biocontainers/salmon:1.2.1--hf69c8f4_0'
shell = ['/bin/bash', '-euo', 'pipefail']


process INDEX {

  script:
  """
  salmon index \
  -t /hpc/genome/gencode.v39.transcripts.fa \
  -i index \
  """
}


workflow {
  INDEX()
}
```

I run it using this command:

```
nextflow run index.nf -resume
```

But got this error:

```
salmon: command not found
```

Do you know how I can fix the issue?

Answer (score 3):

You are so close! All you need to do is move these [directives](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#directives) into your [nextflow.config](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/config.html#configuration-file) or declare them at the top of your process body:

```
container = 'quay.io/biocontainers/salmon:1.2.1--hf69c8f4_0'
shell = ['/bin/bash', '-euo', 'pipefail']
```

My preference is to use a [process selector](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/config.html#process-selectors) to assign the container directive. So for example, your `nextflow.config` might look like:

```
process {

    shell = ['/bin/bash', '-euo', 'pipefail']

    withName: INDEX {
        container = 'quay.io/biocontainers/salmon:1.2.1--hf69c8f4_0'
    }
}

singularity {

    enabled = true

    // not strictly necessary, but highly recommended
    cacheDir = '/path/to/singularity/cache'
}
```

And your `index.nf` might then look like:

```
nextflow.enable.dsl=2

params.transcripts = '/hpc/genome/gencode.v39.transcripts.fa'


process INDEX {

    input:
    path fasta

    output:
    path 'index'

    """
    salmon index \\
        -t "${fasta}" \\
        -i index \\
    """
}


workflow {

    transcripts = file( params.transcripts )

    INDEX( transcripts )
}
```

If run using:

```
nextflow run -ansi-log false index.nf
```

You should see the following results:

```
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 21.04.3
Launching `index.nf` [clever_bassi] - revision: d235de22c4
Pulling Singularity image docker://quay.io/biocontainers/salmon:1.2.1--hf69c8f4_0 [cache /path/to/singularity/cache/quay.io-biocontainers-salmon-1.2.1--hf69c8f4_0.img]
[8a/279df4] Submitted process > INDEX
```

Comment: I added the whole results below.

Comment: @user7249622 Instead of adding that as an answer, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70904487/edit) your question to include this output.

Comment: @user7249622 My guess is that `/hpc/deve/work` doesn't actually exist on your filesystem? This is likely a configuration problem. And it might be a Singularity question for your HPC admin. Could your `/etc/singularity/singularity.conf` (or equivalent) be missing a bind path? For example: `bind path = /hpc`?

Comment: I checked all the items you mentioned. actually `/hpc/deve/work` is where I am running so exist. also `/etc/singularity/singularity.conf` exists. but I did not understand: `be missing a bind path? For example: bind path = /hpc`
what should a I do with it?

Comment: @user7249622 No worries! If it helped you out, please consider marking it as accepted. Cheers.